# Tangent Space to the Quadratic Form

Tags: algebraic-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, tangent-bundle, submanifold

Let $S:=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : x^\top Ax = 1 \}$. We know that $S$ is a $(n-1)$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ because it is a regular level set of a smooth function. What is the tangent space to $S$ at a given point $x_0$ (probably in terms of matrix $A$)? We can assume that $A$ is symmetric and invertible. 
Thank you, in advance, for your response!

Comment: The tangent space to any point in any smooth manifold is a vector space of dimension equal to the dimension of the manifold at that point. Are you looking for a different description?

Comment: @KReiser: Thanks for your comment. I am thinking if there exists a more specific description for this manifold.

Comment: I wanted to use the following definition: "set of all equivalence classes of curves that have value $x_0$ at $t=0$". However, I do not know how to use it in this case.

Comment: I suggest you show that on $\Bbb R^n$, your definition gives that the tangent space is $\Bbb R^n$. Then you can say that on any smooth manifold, the tangent space at a point is just a vector space of dimension equal to dimension of the manifold, as a manifold is locally isomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: @KReiser: I guess you mean the "tangent bundle" is $\mathbb{R}^n$. Your description is correct.

Comment: We know that the tangent space (not bundle) at a given point is a vector space of dimension $(n-1)$. But what is the description of that vector space in terms of matrix $A$?

Comment: Ah, that's what you were after. Please edit your question to make that clear - it will help you get a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm using the Einstein summation notation, and that $A$ is symmetric.)

If you differentiate the function $f(x) = x^T A x = x_i A_{ij} x_j$, you get :

$f_k(x) = A_{kj} x_j + x_i A_{ik} = 2 A_{kj} x_j$

This lets you compute the gradient of $f$ , namely $\nabla f = 2 [ A_{1j} x_j, \ldots, A_{nj} x_j]$.

Now you can use the fact that the tangent space to a hypersurface is the hyperplane orthogonal to the gradient vector.

Discussion:

In particular, if you think of the variety as being defined by the restriction of the quadratic form $Q(v,w) = v^T A w$ to the diagonal $\{ (v,v) : v \in \mathbb{R}^n \} \cong \mathbb{R}^n$, and on the diagonal setting setting $Q(v,v) = 1$, then you can think of the tangent space to $Q(v,v)=1$  at $v$ as being defined by the linear form $Q(v,\_) = 0$.

Yet another point of view: we can think of $Q$ as defining an linear map $\tilde{Q} : \mathbb{R}^n \to (\mathbb{R}^n)^*$, namely $v \to Q(v, \_)$. Then the map that sends a point to it's normal (translated to the origin) is just the restriction of $\tilde{Q}$ to the set $Q(v,v) = 1$. (This is the Gauss map: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_map )

Example:

A good example to think about all of this is the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$. I'll leave it to you to work out the details in these cases, where you can check your computations against visual intuition.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have calculated the tangent space to the  unit circle and sphere. Honestly, I am not familiar with "variety " and other differential geometry concepts in the later part of your response. I wanted to use the basic definition of tangent space to this submanifold.

Comment: @Arthur Variety is just the set of points defined by some equation, like $x^T A x = 1$. The crucial sentance is this one: "Now you can use the fact that the tangent space to a hypersurface is the hyperplane orthogonal to the gradient vector." All I was doing in the first paragraph is computing the gradient, which is calculus. You can safely ignore the "discussion"

Comment: Thanks for clarification! As you said, the gradient at $x_0$ is $2Ax_0$ which is orthogonal to each level set, and thus, orthogonal to each tangent vector at that point. Therefore, we can say $T_{x_0}S= \{ x_0\} \times  \{ v \in \mathbb{R}^n : (2Ax_0)^\top v =  0 \}$. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

If we find a chart $(W,G)$ for the $k$-dim submanifold $S$ at point $x_0$, we can describe the tangent space as
$$T_{x_0}S=\{x_0\} \times \{ v \in \mathbb{R}^n: v=DG(G^{-1}(x_0))\xi, \xi \in \mathbb{R}^k  \}.$$
For example, if we consider the submanifold $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, and assume that $(x_0,y_0) \in \{(x,y): y=+\sqrt{1-x^2} \}$, then we have:
$$T_{x_0}S=\{(x_0,y_0)\} \times \{ v \in \mathbb{R}^2: v=(\xi,\frac{-x_0}{\sqrt{1-x_0^2}} \xi), \xi \in \mathbb{R}  \}. $$
Similarly, we can describe the tangent space for other points on this manifold. My question is that: How can we generalize this? i.e., what is a local chart for the submanifold $x^\top A x = 1$ ?